# Forced assign value to function call

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that the buildin function can be replaced by this way.

```
>>> import os
>>> print(os.system)
<built-in function system>

>>> os.system = "a"
>>> print(os.system)
a
```

For some reason, I can not write `os.system` in source code directly. Then I tried `getattr`. But it doesn't work.

```
>>> import os
>>> print(getattr(os, "system"))
<built-in function system>

>>> getattr(os, "system") = "a"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Is that possible to achieve this?

Comment: What does "I can not write os.system in source code directly" mean?

Comment: @JETM: For my purpose, I can not hardcode module, class or function name into my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getattr` only gets an attribute. Besides that, the error indicates that a function call is not a valid [*assignment target*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-target_list).

What you want is `setattr`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os_system = os.system
>>> setattr(os, 'system', 'a')
>>> getattr(os, 'system')
'a'
>>> setattr(os, 'system', os_system)
>>> getattr(os, 'system')
<built-in function system>
```

---

<sub>*I do hope you have a good reason for doing this.*</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope you can explain more about the implementation of `getattr`. How to forbid function to be assigned value?